# How to force the screen orientation to portrait before starting an App?

Tags: android

I am using the following line of code for each of my activities in order to force the screen orientation to portrait mode:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

It works ok unless I put the device in landscape mode **before** launching the app. In this case, the activity closes suddenly.

Any idea on how to manage this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `android:screenOrientation = "portrait"` in your activity tag.

Comment: I don't want to put this on the Manifest file because the application will be filtered on the Android Market.